# Not able to get authentication token on Postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to learn Spring security using JWT method. While doing this there is no error in program, but I am not getting token on my Postman client.

Here is my code:
( here I am not dealing with any database, so created fake username and password )

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        if(userName.equals("foo"))
            return new User("foo", "foo" , new ArrayList<>());
        else
             throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found");
    } 
}
```

(Controller code )

```
public class JwtController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtutil;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/token" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> generateToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest jwtRequest ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(jwtRequest);

        try
        {
            this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtRequest.getUsername()
                    , jwtRequest.getPassword()));
        }
        catch(UsernameNotFoundException e)
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Bad Credentials");
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = this.customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(jwtRequest.getUsername());

        String token = this.jwtutil.generateToken(userDetails);
        System.out.println("JWT Token "+ token);

        // Now we want to send this token back to client
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }
}
```

(Configuration code )

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
       
    }    

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/token")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

(Jwt Request and response )

```
public class JwtRequest {
    
    private String username;
    private String password;        
// getters and setters and constructors        
}      
     
public class JwtResponse {
    
     String token;
// getters and setters and constructors
}
```

Jwtutil class code I have copied from
[JwtUtil.java](https://github.com/koushikkothagal/spring-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/io/javabrains/springsecurityjwt/util/JwtUtil.java)

Postman request

```
{
    "username": "foo",
    "password": "foo"
}
```

Postman response

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-20T05:21:01.251+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/token"
}
```

Where am I wrong ?  Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add @RestController to your JwtController class to make it available :)